# assignment in PHP

Tags: php

I am learning php and read this example in this http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php tutorial,
I want to understand what occur when assigning the return value of method to a variable, why it may change?? please see my questions in the code.

```
<?php

public function myMethod()
{
return 'test';
}

public function myOtherMethod()
 {
 return null;
 }

if($val = $this->myMethod())
{
  // $val might be 1 instead of the expected 'test'  
                                                    ** why it may returns 1??**

}

if( ($val = $this->myMethod()) )
{
// now $val should be 'test'
}

// or to check for false
if( !($val = $this->myMethod()) )                    **what happens here????**
{
 // this will not run since $val = 'test' and equates to true
 }

// this is an easy way to assign default value only if a value is not returned:

if( !($val = $this->myOtherMethod()) )             **what happens here????**
{
$val = 'default'
}

?>
```

Comment: I'm surprised this code even runs, you should not be prefixing your calls with `$this`.

Comment: It doesn't seem you're in the scope of an instantiated object, so that I also don't understand why you have a $this there.

Comment: Where/how you test $val? testing value returned from expression like `!($val = $this->myMethod())` - would evaluate to FALSE/TRUE because of the logical NOT operator `!`. Show us the output with the function `var_dump()`.

Comment: I just copy and past the example from the tutorial :S

Comment: @Alaa: Oh that code is in the comments. Do NOT learn from that code, it's wrong! Simply ignore it, until you understand PHP. It's best for you to stick with the actual tutorial & ignore the comments/"User Contributed Notes" section that's beneath the tutorial.

Comment: @Dor, I already write it in my post, line 2.

Comment: To execute the code I remove "public" keyword and "this->" .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case:

```
if($val = $this->myMethod())
{
  // $val might be 1 instead of the expected 'test'  

}
```

I don't think that's true. $val should be 'test' here. Maybe in older versions of PHP there could have been a bug.

```
if(!($val = $this->myMethod()))
{
 // this will not run since $val = 'test' and equates to true
}
```

Here myMethhod() is executed and returns 'test' which is assigned to $val. Then the result of that assignment is boolean negated. Since the string 'test' evaluates to true, !('test') evalutes to false and the if statement doesn't run.

```
if(!($val = $this->myOtherMethod()))
{
$val = 'default';
}
```

This is the opposite case. $val becomes null. And null evaluates to boolean false, so !(null) evaluates to true and the code in the block executes. So after this code runs $val contains 'default'; This poster is showing this as a way of assigning a default value to $val in the case that $this->myOtherMethod() fails to return anything useful.

Comment: This example illustrate the assignment operation not the comparison.

Comment: @Alaa Yes. That is the assignment operator. To do a comparison you would need an extra `=` like `$val == $this->myMethod()`

Comment: can u tell me what is the difference between == and === ?

Comment: @Alaa `===` compares the value and type of each side of the expression While `==` compares just the value. For example: `42 === '42'` evaluates to false since 42 is an int but '42' is a string, while `42 == '42'` evaluates to true since after they are converted to the same type, they are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

why it may returns 1? It is not returning 1 but the actual value that is 'test' but since this value is assigned properly because this is not NULL, false or empty. the if statement evaluates to true.

```
    // or to check for false
    if( !($val = $this->myMethod()) )                    **what happens here????**
    {
        // this will not run since $val = 'test' and equates to true
    }
```

What is happening here? The if statement here will test if non NULL value has been assigned to $val i.e. $val is not null similar to if(!$val). Since its value is not NULL nor false The code inside if will not execute.

```
    if( !($val = $this->myOtherMethod()) )             **what happens here????**
    {
        $val = 'default'
    }
```

What is happening here? since the assignment to the $val inside if statement failed because function returned NULL, and since $val is NULL if statement evaluates true and code inside executes. It wouldn't execute if the function had returned other than NULL or false.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry guys, but i think the previous answers are wrong. I'm not sure if this is a typo or a trick question, but with

```
if($val = $this->myMethod())
```

you're actually SETTING $val to whatever $this->myMethod() returns, so your if() statement always equals true here. if you want to compare it you would have to use

```
if($val == $this->myMethod())
```

Notice the '==' in here!

Comment: but the example is for assignment not for comparison, check the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
public function myMethod()
{
return 'test';
}

public function myOtherMethod()
 {
 return null;
 }

if($val = myMethod())
{
    Do Something
}elseif ($val != myMethod()){
    Do Something Else
}elseif ($val == myOtherMethod())
{
$val = 'default';
}

?>
```